# Could not find developer disk image xcode 7.2 / OS X 10.10.5 . IOS 9.3

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am getting the "Could not find developer disk image" error message when trying to run my App on my phone.  Software versions:

xcode 7.2 / OS X 10.10.5  / IOS 9.3

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please search before posting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your Xcode version

Comment: And updating to Xcode 7.3 requires OS X 10.11.